Selenium python, get_attribute() returns none
I am using gps-coordinates.net to find latitude and longitude of different locations. I am trying to read from the html what the latitude would be. The text I am trying to read is in an input field.  The html is below:
<input id="latitude" class="form-control" type="text">

I have tried the get_attribute function as below, and with a variety of different arguments. I have also tried using the .text method, which does not work. I am expecting a string of numbers, but am receiving None.
lat = browser.find_element(By.ID,'latitude')
print(lat.get_attribute('value'))

The above approach works to find the value of the address from the address input field, but not from the coordinate input field. Below is the html for the address input field.
<input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" value="New York">


It seems the value is indeed not defined at that moment. If you try to interact with the website manually, you will see that in the beginning there is no value. It appears only after scrolling down to the map.
